# doing work on stoi() results not working

Tags: c++

Hi I am currently trying to do some work with strings as its easier to handle errors than if you were doing it with say an int.

I have `stoi()` in the program but seem to be getting issues when I try to call the function with the string value and multiply like

```
if(stoi(daysamount)<=3)
    {
        extrascost1=(5*stoi(daysamount));
        extra=extrascost1;
    }
```

what am I doing wrong? Or is there something extra I should be adding in the program just keeps breaking each time I compile... any help would be great.

When i compile it brings up the follow

```
First-chance exception at 0x76C32EEC in ConsoleApplication6.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0019EE60.
```

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued. and brings me into the workings of the function but i dont know what it means.

Comment: Well what's wrong with it? What happens that you don't expect?

Comment: Can you include the compiler errors in your question?  Showing a bit more code would be helpful too.

Comment: From an efficiency standpoint you should assign the result from `stoi` to a variable and then do work with it.  No reason to call it twice.

Comment: It looks like your compiler error is a runtime error.  Can you show more code please?  Preferably a full (but short) program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I would put the rest in but it doesnt seem to want to except it its a function and no matter what i do it says its not formatted even tho i do the exact same as i did with the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no conversion could be performed, an `std::invalid_argument` exception is thrown.
So I suppose that `daysamount` doesn't represent a valid number.

Comment: I think i know what i was doing wrong i had called the function for printing before i had taken alot of details into the strings to be worked on